# How do you write inline Ruby on Rails ternary operators in an HTML tag with white space?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-operator

I'm currently running into a problem where I am trying to make a li tag have specific classes based on a Ruby variable by using a ternary operator:

```
<li class=<%= loc == @ruby_var ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item" %>>
...
</li>
```

I expect the results to be an li element with both the nav-item and active classes if @ruby_var is true:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
...
</li>
```

However, for some reason, I am getting unexpected results where it only sets the class to the first *part* of the string that is in the ternary operator, and leaves the second part outside of the class tag:

```
<li class="nav-item" active>
...
</li>
```

I have tried using more than one space in my "nav-item active" string but any white space seems to make the class only accept the first elem in the string.

What is the proper way to use the ternary operator to set an HTML tag's classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this

```
<li class="<%= loc == @ruby_var ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item" %>">
  # ...
</li>
```

Note the `"` outside of the erb expression.

*Or* you can use [tag helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) like this

```
<%= tag.li, class: ["nav-item", (:active if loc == @ruby_var)] do %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

I like the second option better because I prefer not to mix HTML and ERB when describing a tag.

Comment: The first way worked perfectly, but I'm struggling to understand why it works. Wouldn't the first way return two sets of double-quotes? Such as ""nav-item active""

Comment: No, your version doesn't return any double quotes at all. `<%= "foo" %>` will just insert `foo` into the document, not `"foo"`. That means your version would generate `<li class=nav-item active>` and that will be misunderstand by the browser as the an `li` with a `class` attribute with the value`nav-item` and an unknown `active` attribute.